# Prove if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and $a \neq b$ and $a > 0$, $b > 0$, then $\frac{(a+b)}{2} > \sqrt{ab}$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Prove if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and $a \neq b$ and $a > 0$, $b > 0$, then $\frac{(a+b)}{2} > \sqrt{ab}$

Using a backward proof:

$\frac{(a+b)}{2} > \sqrt{ab}$

$\Rightarrow (a+b)^{2} > 4ab$

$\Rightarrow a^{2}+2ab+b^{2} > 4ab$

$\Rightarrow a^{2}-2ab+b^{2} > 0$

$\Rightarrow (a-b)^{2} > 0 $

The professor ended the proof here, but I'm wondering, how does $(a-b)^{2} > 0 $ show that the assumptions $a > 0$ and $b > 0$ are satisfied?

Comment: Assumptions do not need to be shown to hold. They are satisfied by assumption.

Comment: Well you are given already that $a>0$ and $b>0$ so they must be positive. Try proving the contrapositive and it might shed some light on why it holds.

Comment: Its given to you that $a,b>0$. Answer to yourself the following question: when does $x^2$ is greater than zero?

Comment: Otherwise you cannot put $\sqrt{ab}$. And also this is part of the  hypothesis. Make no sense if not. A better form to enunciate the statement is the following: $$\forall a,b>0\left(a\neq b\Rightarrow \frac{a+b}{2}>\sqrt{ab}\right)$$ from ths is easy to see which are the hypothesis.

Comment: I imagine too, that you want to avoid trouble when taking $\sqrt{ab}$ , then you don't want $a,b$ with different signs.

Comment: @IttayWeiss So how do I know that I've reached the end of the proof in a backward proof method?

Comment: I'm hoping your professor wrote $\iff$ instead of $\implies$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. The assumption is needed in the "forward" proof.

$$(a-b)^2 > 0$$
$$\implies a^2 - 2ab + b^2 > 0$$
$$\implies a^2 + 2ab + b^2 > 4ab$$
$$\implies (a+b)^2 > 4ab$$

The assumptions $a>0$ and $b>0$ are needed for the final step:

$$\implies \frac{a+b}{2} > \sqrt{ab}$$

The point is that they allow us to take the *positive* square root of both sides.

Comment: So how does backward proof work? I thought the idea for a backward proof is to start with what I want to prove and show that it traces back to the beginning?

Comment: The backwards proof doesn't really prove anything, but it does suggest how to write the forwards proof, and what assumptions may be needed.