# Error in demonstration of $(a-b)^{2} \ge 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

It's a fact that:

$\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$

When a and b are non negative real numbers. What's the error in the following demonstration:

$\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$ , then

$a+b \ge 2\sqrt{ab}$ , then

$a^{2}+2ab+b^{2} \ge 4ab$ , then

$a^{2}-2ab+b^{2} \ge 0$ , then

$(a-b)^{2} \ge 0$

discrete math professor gave that question as homework, and this is a direct translation from portuguese.

the only idea I have is to say that both $(a-b)^{2}\ge 0$ and $(b-a)²\ge 0$ are valid, but it only specifies one. Is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Who says there’s an error?  $(a-b)^2=(b-a)^2$

Comment: How do you "know" $(a+b)/2 > \ge \sqrt{ab}$? The usual way to prove that starts with $(a-b)^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/595034/532409 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2343337/532409 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/557653/532409 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4614921/532409

Comment: Why do you think there's an error?

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* with that demonstration.  It just doesn't mean anything as $(a-b)^2\ge 0$ is *always* true =whether $\frac {a+b}2 \ge \sqrt ab$  or not.  You might as well say "Fish like tacos $\implies a-b\in \mathbb R \implies (a-b)^2 \ge 0$.  The thing though is *EVERY* step is reversible.  $\frac {a+b}2\ge \sqrt{ab}\iff a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}\iff (a+b)^2\ge 4ab$ **AND** $a,b\ge 0\iff a^2+2ab +b^2 \ge 4ab;a,b\ge 0\iff a^2-2ab-b^2\ge 0;a,b\ge 0\iff (a-b)^2\ge 0;a,b\ge 0$. As $(a-b)^2\ge 0$ always and we were *told* $a,b\ge 0$ this means we have proven $\frac {a+b}2\ge \sqrt{ab}$.

Comment: @fleablood. What happens if we assume the negation? $\frac{a + b}{2} < \sqrt {ab} \implies a + b < 2\sqrt {ab} \implies a^2 + b^2 + 2ab < 4ab \implies a^2 - 2ab + b^2 < 0 \implies \left(a - b \right)^2 < 0$

Comment: Then that would be a proof by contradiction because we know $(a-b)^2 \not < 0$.

Comment: To me this issue is the word "demonstration".  Was this a mistranslation of the word "proof"?   A "demonstration" isn't a proof.  A demonstration is just "here I showed you something".  And there's nothing wrong in what is being shown.  But as a *proof*.  What's wrong is you can' prove something by assuming it is true and coming to a true conclusion.  That only shows that assuming something true didn't lead to an obvious contradict. Here's a proof that it rains lemonade. Assume it rains lemonade. Then after a rain the ground would be wet. The ground *is* wet after a rain. So it rains lemonade.

Comment: All that's wrong here is that "then" should read "because", i.e., the proof presents the right steps but connects them in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake in proofs to *assume* the truth of what you wish to prove. Once that has been done, you can prove $anything$.

For example, here is an absurd "proof" that
$$2=3\Rightarrow 0=0\Rightarrow \text{Last statement is valid}$$

The above proof would have been correct if you begin with the last step, and work backwards.

Or, if you write at the very end that:
All steps are reversible.

That last statement, of course, needs to be checked very carefully.